Would it be ok/useful to mirror a SATA HD or SSD with an nvme SSD?
I have a laptop with a 2TB SATA SSD which also has an M.2 NVME slot with currently a 128GB SSD inside. I wondered if it would help to put a 2TB SSD in the NVME slot and mirror both ? The reasoning behind this is that and SSD failure could lose the whole content without a warning, and that since a mirror only needs to access the fastest device when reading with no read error, mirroring it on a faster SSD could enhance the reading access (not the writes, obviously). By the way I have no idea how to do software mirroring on windows.
I currently have a windows 10 inside, but I intend to add a linux on a second partition.

what hardware/software would you use as your controller?

As mentioned : it is a laptop (home) computer (i.e. I doubt I could find any hardware mirroring function in it), and I have no idea how to do software mirroring on windows. (I.e. any help on that would be welcome too). (On linux I would use mdadm but linux is not installed yet, and I never used it on a boot disk, but I doubt it would make any problem for a simple mirroring)

I'm afraid this question is pretty opinion-oriented. Personally my take is you are introducing a lot of (software) complexity that will likely reduce performance, and on a device where the high-availability of a Raid1 would not be particularly useful to the devices role. instead mabey consider using it for backups, so you get most of the additional data-loss protection, without all the software dependencies and complexity. Just my two bits. I tend to be a bit conservative about RAID outside the enterprise, and with 2 OSs you can't even software raid at the disk level.

Uh ? Why couldn't you ? What would prevent you from duplicating every write from one physical disk to the other - whatever the partition ?

because the mirroring is being provided as a feature of the booted operating system, whichever one is running at the same time. its unlikely that the mdadm raid and the windows storage spaces raid work identically. I'd guess you would corrupt your whole disk the second you booted the second OS, but that is just a guess.

Well... That would be true for any other redundancy system, but... ? I might be wrong, but It seems that a mirror should just be a mirror, shouldn't it ? I mean... If it wasn't the case, I suppose you wouldn't be able to boot from it without having the mirror software activated first... ?

correct, which is why hardware raid is used in enterprise systems. using a hybrid hardware/software raid like Intel RST also operates below the OS, and should work for multiboot since it is the only system managing the disks, but a purely software solution will leave whatever OS is booted managing them. you may be able to get away with mirroring partitions, provided each mirror is only managed in one OS.

Mirroring partitions won't work because I want to have an NTFS shared space where both OSes can write to exchange files.
